# Set cron schedule for Jenkins job by non-Administrators

Tags: jenkins, cron, admin

We the admins have set the cron for a particular job.

The end user(non-admin) has requested that they wish to change the cron timings twice every week for a Jenkins job.

The end user does not have admin priveledges but has requested if they could change Jenkins cron timings themselves.

Is it possible to give the end-user the ability to set the cron for thier particular job  themselves somehow either for a job dsl or for a pipeline?

Comment: which authorization are you using?

Comment: Saml 2.0 ADFS role based authorization

Comment: OK. I think if you're using role based authorization with SAML for your projects, you can enable a user to use CRON in matrix authorization itself.

Comment: @Swaps thats what I'm using, however, can you tell me where can I find or setup the option to get the user just to the cron configuration? I followed the document here: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/03/jenkins-users-groups-roles/

Comment: I don't think atleast at this point there is any plugin available which can allow user auth inside the `job configuration`. So best is you'd need to give a `configuration` permission to the user for which you want to enable `CRON`.